# How to handle signin views

Tags: swift, asynchronous, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a swift 3, xcode 8, ios10, Firebase dev. project and trying to build a login / createuser flow. I have three views -

1. Mainview (the app)
2. Loginview
3. Createuserview

When the app loads I check if the user is logged in at "viewDidAppear" in Mainview, if not I open LoginView. If the user goes from view 2 to view 3 - the createuserview and creates a useraccount I cant dismiss (close) view 2 and and get the "viewDidAppear" in view 1 to fire and to check if the user is logged in.

The useraccount is created and sign in correctly but I cant dismiss the views 2, and 3 and open the view 1 (Mainview). And if the mainview is opened, the view must check if the user is signed in and not open the view 2 (login) agin which could be difficult with async. programming.

Thanks for any help, I am really stuck here. Some code in view 1 -

```
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        super.viewDidAppear(true)       

        print("*** viewDidAppear ***")

        if FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser != nil {

            print("CHECK - USER LOGGED IN")

        } else {

            print("CHECK - USER LOGGED OUT")
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueLogin", sender: nil)
            return

        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After successfully creating a new user in View 3 : Createuserview fire a delegate method to get back to View 2

```
protocol NewUserCreatedSuccessProtocol {
   func userCreatedSuccessAndReturn(user : FirebaseUser)
}

class CreateUserview {
   var delegate : NewUserCreatedSuccessProtocol! = nil
   func handleSignUp() {
       if delegate != nil {
          self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
          self.delegate.userCreatedSuccessAndReturn(user: Insert())
       }
   }
}


extension LoginView : NewUserCreatedSuccessProtocol {

   func userCreatedSuccessAndReturn(user : FirebaseUser) {
     self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
   }  
}
```

This way you can dismiss from both of the views on successfully creating new user. You can also show an alert before dismissing.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I made a similar version but connects the delegate in prepare(for segue...). I had also solution with unwind segue. Thanks